# CSS ':checked' not working

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
...
<input id ="nav-toggle" type="checkbox">
<label id ="nav-toggle-label" for="nav-toggle">
    <img src="ic_view_list_white_18px.svg">
</label>
...
```

CSS

```
...    
header #nav-toggle {
    display: none;
}
header #nav-toggle-label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.3ch;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#nav-toggle:checked + header + article {
    margin-left: 20ch;
}
...
```

Been trying to create a checkbox that'll toggle a sidebar (`nav`) by sliding `header` and `article` to the right.
It's not working for some reason, would appreciate any help.

Comment: Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` is the **Adjacent Sibling Selector**
your adjacent sibling is not `<header>` but `<label>`.
If your `<article>` is a later sibling element use the `~` **General Sibling Combinator** selector...

Or do it this way:

```css
#nav-toggle { /* remove "header" */
    display: none;
}
#nav-toggle-label { /* remove "header" */
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.3ch;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#nav-toggle:checked + article { /* remove the "+header" */
    margin-left: 20ch;
}
```

```html
<header>
  
  <!-- LABEL IS INSIDE <header>... -->
  
  <label id ="nav-toggle-label" for="nav-toggle">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50x50">
  </label>
  
</header>

<!-- BUT PLACE YOUR CHECKBOX RIGHT BEFORE THE DESIRED TOGGLABLE ELEMENT -->

<input id="nav-toggle" type="checkbox">
<article>THIS IS ARTICLE</article>
```

Now the above works cause `+` selects the checkbox immediate next sibling: `article`

Comment: I didn't manage to implement it like you described. I have **two** tags to act on, `header` and `nav`. my checkbox (along with the label) are inside `header` now. I tried to move the `input` tag in between `header` and `nav` but it still does't work. I need a way to get to the parent tag (for `header`) and to `nav` which is `header`'s adjacent sibling.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot # before nav-toggle in yur css

Comment: Sorry, a copy-paste mistake. The code still doesn't work of course.

Comment: why is #nav-toggle  display: none ?

Comment: @Raf because it's used as a toggler. Logically.

Comment: ok. have you tried the code with checkbox visible? Maybe it's not being checked on click when not visible If so try adding opacity:0 instead

Comment: @Raf it has nothing to do with `:checked`-ability. Setting to `none` might only have issues in the value being (not) submitted by a form.

Comment: @Raf I did. the checkbox is checked when I click on it, but there's no action. It's like the browser ignore the `:checked` and doesn't know it exists.